# Constructor invocation in C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I tried to find out the output of this program in C++.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyInt {
    int i;
    public:
        MyInt() {
            cout<<1;
            i = 0;
        }
        MyInt(int i) {
            cout<<2;
            this->i = i;
        }
        int value(){
            return i;
        }
};

int main() {
    MyInt i;
    i = 10;
    cout<<i.value();
}
```

I expected the output to be `210` but the output of the program is `1210`.
So why are both the default constructor and parameterized constructor invoked in this case?

Comment: `MyInt i;` invokes the default constructor.

Comment: `MyInt i;` -- Not sure what you expected this to do, since you are constructing a `MyInt` object, and constructing an object means a constructor will be invoked.  Maybe if you named your variable something other than `i`, the picture will be a little bit more clear?

Comment: One word tip; whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyInt i;
```

The above line invokes `MyInt::MyInt()`, creating an object and outputting `1`.

```
i = 10;
```

The above line invokes `MyInt::MyInt(int i)`, creating another object and outputting `2`.  The second object is then assigned to the first object, which outputs nothing.

```
cout<<i.value();
```

The above line invokes `MyInt::value()`, outputting `10`.

Comment: Which line actually created the object? The object is created only once, so why is the constructor called twice, once without parameter and again with parameter 10?

Comment: @brahmdevpandey You’re actually creating multiple `MyInt` objects: you are attempting to assign `10` to `i`, but `10` is an `int`, it needs to be converted to a `MyInt` before the assignment can succeed. And this (implicit) conversion happens via the `MyInt(int)` constructor.

Comment: @brahmdevpandey `MyInt` does not implement an `operator=(int)` assignment operator, but the compiler does auto-generate a default `operator=(const MyInt &)` copy assignment operator. So, when you assign an `int` to an existing `MyInt` object, the compiler sees that `operator=` takes in a `MyInt` object, and a `MyInt` object can be (implicitly) constructed from an `int` via the `MyInt(int)` constructor (which is not marked `explicit`), so a temporary `MyInt` can be created to satisfy the assignment. IOW, it treats `i = 10;` as `i = MyInt(10);` That is where the 2nd `MyInt` object is coming from

Comment: @KonradRudolph @RemyLebeau Oh. Got it. So does it means that if I try to assign a String to the ```MyInt``` object ```i```, the compiler should give an error?

Comment: And yes. The compiler does give the error of ```ambiguous overload of operator=```. Thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print 210 you should write:

```
MyInt i = 10;
std::cout << i.value();
```

MyInt i; calls the default constructor. That is why you are printing 1 first.